# How to find ancestors more than one level above

Tags: xslt, ancestor

I need to check for condition in XSLT where parent_of 'c' should be 'b'  but ancestor of 'c' should not be 'a'? How can i achieve this ?

```
<a1>
 <a>
  <b>
   <c> </c> 
  </b>  
 </a>
<a1>
```

Comment: Could you give us a simple example of an XSLT snippet where you would use this condition? What would the context node be in this case?

Answer (score 1):

To check whether the current node matches your description:

```
self::c[parent::b and not(ancestor::a)]
```

To select all elements in the document that match your description (or check whether there are any):

```
//b/c[not(ancestor::a)]
```

Given a more clearly explained use case, there may be a path that's better suited to your situation, and if so, please let us know. Hopefully the above sets you on the right track.